# how deploying importing busines network on hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

how to  deploy the business network  on hyperledger composer through cli?

> student-business-network@0.0.2-deploy.3 prepublish /home/user/Downloads/student-business-network.bna_FILES
>   mkdirp ./dist && composer archive create  --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/unnamed-network.bna

Creating Business Network Archive

Looking for package.json of Business Network Definition
    Input directory: /home/user/Downloads/student-business-network.bna_FILES

Found:
    Description: Start from scratch with a blank business network
    Name: student-business-network
    Identifier: student-business-network@0.0.2-deploy.3

Written Business Network Definition Archive file to 
    Output file: ./dist/unnamed-network.bna

Command succeeded

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN student-business-network@0.0.2-deploy.3 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 933 packages from 1011 contributors and audited 15581 packages in 47.456s
found 111 vulnerabilities (71 low, 26 moderate, 13 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
user@finatel:~/Downloads/student-business-network.bna_FILES$ composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName student-network  && composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile student-business-network.bna --file networkadmin.card && composer card import --file networkadmin.cardcomposer hiveFile student-business-network.bna --file networkadmin.card

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read the hyperledger composer documentation and specifically follow the tutorials in the documentation to help you get started.

documentation can be found here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/

tutorials are here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv12'
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Cannot use v0.19.14 version of composer with fabric 1.2, v0.20 or higher is required

Comment: So you have a choice, you can either uninstall the current version of composer and install 0.20 as the error message says or you can set FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11 and use fabric 1.1 with composer 0.19